# os.getcwd() throws Exception

Tags: python

I have situation when the current directory becomes invalid (ie, when some program deletes it). My Python script calls `os.getcwd()` which terminates with following exception

`OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Ideally, it my script would automatically cd into parent directory in such situation.
When is the recommended strategy for implementing this?

Note, if I try `ls` from the shell, I get `ls: cannot open directory .: Stale NFS file handle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ideally, it my script would automatically cd into parent directory in such situation. When is the recommended strategy for implementing this?

Just use  `try/except` block for that, that's what for we have them :)

```
try:
    os.getcwd()
except OSError:
    os.chdir("..")
    os.getcwd()
```

or something similar...

[edit] Anyway I guess such situation is realy bad for your app - deleted dir, or broken NFS connection etc, and this probably should not be silienced by just change dir - it depends on app of course...